# How to create new ancestor elements with XSLT and change the order of others?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a list of `biblStruct` that needs to be modified using XSLT. The input looks like this:

```
 <biblStruct>
           <title type="label">Volmer 2001</title>
           <author>
              <persName>Volmer, Annett</persName>
           </author>
           <title type="titel">Die Gebrechen des Lebens. Zur Körpererfahrung in
        Korrespondenzen des 18. Jahrhunderts</title>
           <note type="faustdb">biogra</note>
           <idno>3257</idno>
           <note type="objektart">Bibliographie</note>
           <idno>3257</idno>
           <note type="objektart">Bibliographie</note>
           <title type="label">Volmer 2001</title>
           <author>
              <persName>Volmer, Annett</persName>
           </author>
           <title type="titel">Die Gebrechen des Lebens. Zur Körpererfahrung in
        Korrespondenzen des 18. Jahrhunderts</title>
           <biblScope unit="sammelwerkin">Objekt 6677 / Biographien-Werke</biblScope>
           <biblScope unit="sammelwerkseiten">138-149</biblScope>
           <idno type="standortsign">UB Basel: AP IX 5844</idno>
           <note type="erstellt">
              <date>2005-01-19T00:00:00.000</date>
           </note>
           <note type="letztebearb">
              <date>2016-10-10T00:00:00.000</date>
           </note>
           <note type="kategorie">Briefkultur, Netzwerke,
        Transfer;Wissen(schaft)sgeschichte/Medizin</note>
        </biblStruct>
```

I need to:

- Create an element `analytic`that groups elements from `title type="label"` to `note type="objektart">`;
- Create an element `monogr` that groups from the second `title type="label"` to `idno type="standortsign"`;
- Create an element `imprint` nested inside `monogr`-- this new element should contain a new element `publisher` and the existing elements `biblScope`;
- Move all notes outside `analytic` and `monogr` at the end.

The output should look like this:

```
 <biblStruct xml:id="volmer_2001">

           <analytic>
              <author>
                 <persName>Volmer, Annett</persName>
              </author>
              <title type="titel">Die Gebrechen des Lebens. Zur Körpererfahrung in
                 Korrespondenzen des 18. Jahrhunderts</title>
              <idno>3257</idno>
           </analytic>

           <monogr>
              <author>
                 <persName>Volmer, Annett</persName>
              </author>
              <title type="titel">Die Gebrechen des Lebens. Zur Körpererfahrung in
                 Korrespondenzen des 18. Jahrhunderts</title>
              <idno type="standortsign">UB Basel: AP IX 5844</idno>
              <idno>3257</idno>
              <imprint>
                 <publisher></publisher>
                 <biblScope unit="sammelwerkin">Objekt 6677 / Biographien-Werke</biblScope>
                 <biblScope unit="sammelwerkseiten">138-149</biblScope>
              </imprint>
           </monogr>

           <note type="faustdb">biogra</note>
           <note type="objektart">Bibliographie</note>
           <note type="kategorie">Briefkultur, Netzwerke, Transfer;
              Wissen(schaft)sgeschichte/Medizin</note>
           <note type="erstellt">
              <date>2005-01-19</date>
           </note>
           <note type="letztebearb">
              <date>2016-10-10</date>
           </note>

        </biblStruct>
```

Comment: You mention a second `title type="label"`in your question, but your XML only shows one. Can you also say whether you are able to use XSLT 2.0? Thank you

Comment: Yes, XSLT 2.0 would work. In the input snippet the second <title type="lablel"> is placed after <note type="objektart">Bibliographie</note>. However, in the output snippet the second <title type="lablel"> could be removed but I know already how to delete elements -- that is why I did not mention it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using XSLT 2.0, you can make use of the `xsl:for-each-group` construct. You can group all child elements of `biblStruct` (except `note`), by the starting element of `title`

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="* except note" group-starting-with="title[@type='label']">
```

Then, within this, you can test the position to determine whether to create an `analytic` element or an `monogr` element.

```
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
      <analytic>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
      </analytic>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <monogr>
         ...
```

And for the `monogr` element, you would have extra logic to create the `imprint` element, and add the `publisher` and existing `biblScope` elements.

```
  <monogr>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except biblScope" />
     <imprint>
        <publisher />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="biblScope" />
     </imprint>
   </monogr>
```

Try this XSLT (which also includes adding all `note` elements at the end):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="biblStruct">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="* except note" group-starting-with="title[@type='label']">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
            <analytic>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
            </analytic>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <monogr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except biblScope" />
              <imprint>
                <publisher />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="biblScope" />
              </imprint>
            </monogr>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="note" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. However I have realized that the output should be: